# How to set the indent size of bullets in TLF?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, tlf

Is there a property or style that I can use to set the indent size of the bullets in a list in TLF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [listAutoPadding](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/formats/ITextLayoutFormat.html#listAutoPadding) seems to work when importing and exporting TLF markup.

```
<flow:TextFlow whiteSpaceCollapse="preserve" version="3.0.0" xmlns:flow="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008">
    <flow:list listAutoPadding="30" listStyleType="lowerGreek">
        <flow:li>
            <flow:p>
                <flow:span>Bullet List!</flow:span>
            </flow:p>
        </flow:li>
        <flow:li>
            <flow:p>
                <flow:span>line 2</flow:span>
            </flow:p>
        </flow:li>
        <flow:li>
            <flow:p>
                <flow:span>line 3</flow:span>
            </flow:p>
        </flow:li>
    </flow:list>
</flow:TextFlow>
```

Answer (score 0):

element.textIndent or element.paddingLeft